# Jquery .each() - return value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why getColorOptionSelect() return undefined value (I'm sure it has a value by debugger ).

It is for sure an issue related to the scope, sorry for my js ignorance

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    colorSelectID = getColorOptionSelect();
    alert(colorSelectID);

    function getColorOptionSelect() {

        // get label
        var selId;
        jQuery(".product-options dl label").each(function () {
            el = jQuery(this);
            // lower case, remove *
            var labelText = el.text().toLowerCase().replace("*", "");
            if (labelText == 'color') {
                //return element
                selId = el.parent().next().find("select").attr('id');
                return selId;
            }
        });
        //    return null;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4):

`getColorOptionSelect` doesn't have an (uncommented) `return` statement.

The only return statement you have is inside the anonymous function you pass to `each()`. It will be consumed by the code underlying `each()` (which will stop looping if it is `false`).

This isn't a problem of scope, just of there being multiple functions.

You probably want to:

- define a variable before you call `each()`
- assign a value to it inside the each loop
- return that variable at the end of `getColorOptionSelect`

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
function getColorOptionSelect() {

        // get label
        var selId;
        jQuery(".product-options dl label").each(function () {
            el = jQuery(this);
            // lower case, remove *
            var labelText = el.text().toLowerCase().replace("*", "");
            if (labelText == 'color') {
                //return element
                selId = el.parent().next().find("select").attr('id');
                return false; // to stop further execution of each
            }
        });
        return selId;
    }
```

In your case you are doing return from callback function passed to each and it will not be passed from `getColorOptionSelect`

The only thing you can do returning a value from each function callback is to tell jquery if it should go to next item (`return true;`) or not (`return false;`)

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the last `return` statement to retun a value  (something like `selId`)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

colorSelectID = getColorOptionSelect();
alert(colorSelectID);

function getColorOptionSelect() {

    // get label
    var selId;
    jQuery(".product-options dl label").each(function () {
        el = jQuery(this);
        // lower case, remove *
        var labelText = el.text().toLowerCase().replace("*", "");
        if (labelText == 'color') {
            //return element
            selId = el.parent().next().find("select").attr('id');
            return false;  //<---  return false to stop further propagation of each
        }
    });
      return selId; //<---  Must return something 
}

});
```

Comment: Each does not support return like that, hence the error. Toexit each it needs to return false.